# Cant send backgroundImage in props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a problem to pass the backgroundImage this is my code:

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';


import './Home.css';
import AlarmCardInvertida from '../components/AlarmCardInvertida';


function Home() {

    const alarmCardInvertidaData = [
        {
            background: '../../images/banners/casa01.jpg',
        },
    ];

    return (
        <>

            <h2 className='alarm-cards-title'>Funcionalidades de Nuestros Sistemas</h2>
            <section className='alarm-cards-section'>
                {alarmCardInvertidaData.map((card, index) => (
                    <AlarmCardInvertida
                        key={index}
                        background={card.background}
                    />
                ))}
            </section>

        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

And this is my AlarmCardInvertida.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './AlarmCardInvertida.css'

function AlarmCardInvertida(props) {
  const cardStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.background})`,
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: -3,
    width: '100%',
  };


  return (
    <div className='alarm-card-inverted'>
      <div style={cardStyle}></div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default AlarmCardInvertida;
```

The problem is when render:

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;../../images/banners/casa01.jpg&quot;); position: relative; z-index: -3; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Expected:

```
<div style="background-image: url('../../images/banners/casa01.jpg'); position: relative; z-index: -3; width: 100%;"></div>
```

i Try this too:

```
function AlarmCardInvertida(props) {
  const backgroundImageUrl = props.background;

return (
    <div className='alarm-card-inverted'>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImageUrl})`,
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundPosition: 'center',
          width: '100%',
          height: '300px',
        }}
      ></div>
```

and others and render ever ... background-image: url("

Basically the problem I have is that it doesn't render the image inside the backgroundImage (if I send for example to use in a <img src=xxxx tag, this works correctly...) The problem is only with the backgroundImage

Comment: tried `url('${props.background}')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems to be correct to pass the background to the props.

The image may not be showing up since the div containing it is empty. You could try after adding content to it or set a `min-height` value to the div.

I have created a working example here with your code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2qxpar

All I have changed is that I have added the `minHeight` and `backgroundSize` to the AlarmCardInvertida.js within the card style as below and I can see the image load up just fine.

```
  const cardStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.background})`,
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: -3,
    width: '100%',
    minHeight:'500px',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
  };
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
// Home.js
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import AlarmCardInvertida from '../components/AlarmCardInvertida';
import casa01 from '../../images/banners/casa01.jpg'; // import the image

function Home() {
  const alarmCardInvertidaData = [
    {
      background: casa01, // use the imported image
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className='alarm-cards-title'>Funcionalidades de Nuestros Sistemas</h2>
      <section className='alarm-cards-section'>
        {alarmCardInvertidaData.map((card, index) => (
          <AlarmCardInvertida key={index} background={card.background} />
        ))}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;

// AlarmCardInvertida.js
import React from 'react';
import './AlarmCardInvertida.css';

function AlarmCardInvertida(props) {
  const cardStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.background})`,
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: -3,
    width: '100%',
  };

  return (
    <div className='alarm-card-inverted'>
      <div style={cardStyle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AlarmCardInvertida;
```